# About the difference variety of a curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

What is known about the singularity of the difference variety of a smooth curve $C$ of genus g>2? The difference variety is $C-C :=\{\mathcal{O}(p-q)| p,q\in C\} \subset Pic^0C$.

Comment: What do you want to know?  If $C$ is not hyperelliptic, then a log resolution is given of the difference variety is given by the evident morphism $C\times C \to \text{Pic}^0(C)$.  The diagonal in $C\times C$ maps to the singular point.  I would guess that this can be used to compute the discrepancy of the origin inside the difference variety.

Comment: But if $C$ is not hyperelliptic then the morphism $C\times C \rightarrow C-C$ is more complicated. In that case is there a singularity of $C-C$ on the locus where the map is 1:1?

Comment: "In that case is there a singularity of $C - C$ on the locus where the map is $1:1$?"  No, there is no other singular point. First of all, the map is one-to-one on $U=(C\times C)\setminus \Delta_C$, since there is no $g^1_2$.  Second, for a point $(p,q)\in U$, the derivative of the difference map is injective unless the points $\mathbb{P}T_p C$ and $\mathbb{P}T_q C$ of $\mathbb{P}T_0\text{Pic}^0(C)$ coincide.  Since the Gauss map of the Abel map is the canonical map, and this is a closed immersion in the non-hyperelliptic case, the difference map is unramified on $U$.

Comment: By comparing the restriction to $\Delta_C$ of the differential of the "sum" morphism and the "difference" morphism, you can also see that the differential of the difference map has rank $1$ at every point of the diagonal (a similar argument is used to analyze the sum and difference Abel maps for lines on cubic threefolds in my papers with Harris and Roth).  Thus the inverse image scheme of the origin is $\Delta_C$ with multiplicity $1$.  By my computation, the log discrepancy is $-1$, so the singularity is not log canonical.

Comment: I suppose you know the projective tangent cone is the canonical model of the curve if C is not hyperelliptic.  ACGH, Ex. A-5, p.263.

Comment: I am sorry I meant to ask the following: if C is hyperelliptic then the morphism C×C→C−C is more complicated. Outside 0 there is a branch locus where the map is 1:1. In that case is there a singularity of C−C on the locus where the map is 1:1?

Comment: @ydutta: If you look at what Roy Smith and I wrote, you will see that the locus in $U$ where the derivative of the difference map has rank $1$ equals the non-injectivity locus for the canonical map.  Thus, the branch curve in $U$ for the difference map equals the graph of the hyperelliptic involution.  Apart from the singularity at the origin, there is no other singular point on the difference variety in the hyperelliptic case.